# How To Update a Sql Table On Regular Interval

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a Data table in my Sql Database and I want to update some entries in that table on 1 day(regular) interval. How can I do it

Comment: How you will get values for updating so that it replaces the old values?? @raunak

Comment: What kind of an answer do you expect? I'd say write a cron job which would run a query once a day and update the entries you need.

Comment: You can use [events](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/events.html) if the relevant data is contained in your database.

Comment: @Techy I will use update query to change values from 1 to 0 for a column value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this with `Event Scheduler` in `SQL`

```
CREATE EVENT myevent
ON SCHEDULE AT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 1 HOUR
DO
UPDATE myschema.mytable SET mycol = mycol + 1;
```

I hope this may be useful for you...

Since i dont know your scenario..

Answer (score 0):

If this job is in regular basis, try using [Scheduler Events](http://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-create-mysql-events/)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a SSIS package for the same. In SSIS define your source(from where you'll fetch data) and destination(You want to update the data).
Then you can schedule it on a daily basis at what time you want to update the data. This can be easily done through SSIS.

For details on SSIS, you can refer to the following site:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141134.aspx

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this available,

1. Create a cron "daily.job" job as,

   ```
   #!bin/sh
   sqlplus -s /nolog user@schema/password <<EOF
   do your anonymous script here 
   commit;
   exit;
   EOF
   ```

   add this job using crontab, for example in linux use crontab -e command and add 
   an entry to run every day at mid night

   ```
      00 00 * * * $HOME/bin/daily.job >> $HOME/logs/daily.job.log 2>&1
   ```
2. Second option is to write a PL/Sql Procedure and add that as a DB scheduled job.
   If you are using Oracle, please refer to the following link

   http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25494/scheduse.htm#ADMIN034

Comment: Sorry, this is specifically for Oracle + Linux case. Your question was regarding SQL Server.